# VB form timer hungs up

Tags: vb.net

I created an alarm clock with VB form and I noticed that the timer hangs up if I open another app like Chrome browser. If it hangs at 55 sec and then restarts at 05 sec then my clock will have missed 1 min because the minutes only change when the seconds hit 00. Any ideas?

Comment: @Claudius Something tells me there are more friendly ways of saying that same thing, while still being welcoming and forgiving of newcomers... Having a bad day or something? :)  Anyway, despite his tone, he's right.  Without seeing your code, we can merely speculate at what the problem might be.  Try to come up with the smallest amount of code which is able to reproduce the problem, and then edit your question to include a copy of the code.  We'll be able to help you much better that way.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here [ask] and it's also important to look here .. [mcve] .. **Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered** and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Comment: Some code is needed to see what is happeneing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't check for second 0 for the exact reason you are having the problem. Keep a variable of the last execution date. And execute your code if it's been over 1 minutes since the last execution date.

```
Dim previousExecution As DateTime
Dim closestExecution As DateTime

' ...

' Get current time minus seconds
closestExecution = DateTime.Now
closestExecution = closestExecution.AddSeconds(-closestExecution.Second)

If previousExecution < closestExecution Then
    ' Execute your code
    previousExecution = closestExecution
End If
```